# SSH lags, freezes, hangs intermittently

Tags: wifi, ssh, vnc

Rpi is up to date, I have experienced the "hangings" with or without my high speed usb dongle. They happen on both my Rpis 4.
When I use VNC or simply SSH into my Rpi (4gb), everything is fluid, but every now and then both can hang out of nowhere and at the most inconvenient times for about 3 to 7 secs. I have reduced VNC quality thinking it might be a bandwidth issue, but that shouldn't be affecting SSH.
Whatever I do while its hanging then rushes into the pi after the hanging is over. But it can be pretty damaging when I'm controlling my robot. Signal is always at maximum strength.

Any ideas what could be causing the hangs?

thank you

Comment: What operating system do you use? Raspbian Buster?

Comment: Because this is a problem appearing on all connected devices, this is not a specific problem for Raspberry Pi, rather a general network issue. You may get better answers at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Ingo What makes you think this is happening on devices other than RPis please? I can see nothing in the question to suggest it.

Comment: @MarkSmith "*"hangings" with or without my high speed usb dongle*" + "*happen on both my Rpis 4*" + "*both can hang out of nowhere*" + "*have reduced VNC quality*", this all together and the context indicates for me, that it is more a networking WiFi problem and/or the router, than a problem on the RasPi.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. Yes im using Buster. I tend to think as @ingo suggest that it might be a router problem. I will try to create a adhoc connection between my laptop and the Pis and see if the issue persists. That should at least indicate if the issue is in the Pis or the router. It seems is not a common problem.